Connection Reset By Peer from archive.ubuntu.com
Ubuntu 22
I trying to make own ubuntu repository. Recently I created and updated Jammy repos by "aptly mirror update" command from official server.
Now I trying to update xenial repos. In first it was downloading all the things, but now it says:
ERROR: unable to update: download errors:
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool...../something.deb read tcp 192.168.0.24:45936->185.125.190.82:80: read: connection reset by peer
Maybe it kinda ddos guard, but how to fix it?

Ubuntu Core 22 won't be reading packages from archive.ubuntu.com so something is wrong; only 22.04 systems will read from that site.  You didn't provide package details (something.deb isn't valid for any supported release) which allows further investigation, 185.125.190.82 is a Canonical address though.
